# What does this DNS benchmark mean?

Tags: dns

After a DNS benchmark using **DNSBenchmark** I get at the conclusions 2 "warining", but I don't really understand what it means and what I should do:

## ***1. System has only ONE (router based) nameserver configured.***

It appears that only one local (router gateway) DNS nameserver, with the IP address of [192.168.0.1], is currently providing all DNS name resolution services to this system. This configuration is not recommended because most consumer-grade routers provide inefficient and under-powered DNS resolution services.

Unless the DNS resolvers your router is using is under your control, it may not be providing the best or complete name resolution services. For example, is it using multiple redundant DNS nameservers?

Users of GRC's DNS Spoofability system have determined that consumer-grade routers can be crashed by the receipt of specific DNS reply packets from the Internet. This opens the possibility that Internet-based criminals could acquire access to your router from the Internet as well as to the private network in controls.

Many consumer-grade routers fail to provide the full range of DNS lookup services. This may have been detected by the benchmark and noted below.

Recommended Actions:

Unless you have some specific reason not to, you should give serious thought to disabling your router's provisioning of DNS services (which it is providing for all computers on your local network). After this is done, a fresh reboot of your computers will likely reveal the multiple DNS nameservers provided by your ISP. This is a superior configuration, without an under-powered router acting as a incompetent middleman and impeding all DNS access.

Note that if you can determine the IP addresses of your ISP-provided nameservers (which may be visible in your router's web configuration) you could manually add them to the nameservers being tested by this benchmark, while also leaving your router providing DNS. This would allow you to compare the performance when running through your router versus "going direct".

## ***2. System's nameserver is dead & NOT replying to queries!***

It probably comes as no surprise that all of this system's sole DNS resolving nameserver, with the IP address of [192.168.0.1] is apparently dead (at least for the moment) and is not replying to DNS queries since very little of the Internet is accessible without any DNS services.

Recommended Actions:

Since the loss of all DNS services is inconvenient to say the least, switching to a more reliable nameserver, or adding additional backup nameservers, might make a great deal of sense.

This outage might be temporary or easily diagnosed. So you should not consider changing anything until you have some idea whether this trouble is likely to persist or repeat. So you can use this benchmark to check to see how long this problem persists. If this nameserver deadness is chronic, you should definitely consider changing to nameservers that are more reliably operating.

If a local LAN router is providing DNS services to this network, it is possible that a reboot & restart of the router will resolve this outage. Sometimes just the DNS portion of a router dies while everything else continues to function normally.

Since this system only has a single nameserver configured to handle it's DNS services, it would still be advisable, if possible, to configure one or more backup nameservers to provide services in the event of this system's sole nameserver failing for any reason.

I tried to search on google about the problem, but didn't get the answers I looked for.

Comment: This thing? https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm